# Firebase Auth with SSR while still using client library

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Here is my dilemma. I want to use firebase auth, but I also want to server render authenticated content. Since firebase auth uses locally stored jwts, my research tells me that I should be using a cookie. However, if I am to follow the firebase admin docs and implement session cookies, it seems that I will lose out on being able to use the client library. Is there any secure way around this? Or will I be forced to choose. Also, here are the firebase docs that make it seem like I won’t be able to use the firebase client library https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies.

Thanks!